# how to update a checkbox using json and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I've seen this on the account settings page of living social.  Basically there is a checkbox corresponding to a value:

```
Receive email notifications:

When deal is about to run out    Yes    No 
You've earned deal bucks         Yes    No
```

Yes and No are checkboxes.  When the user clicks Yes or No the JS code is making a json POST request to `/deals/people/update_email_setting.json`

Their JS is posted [here](http://pastie.org/2321475) I can make some sense of it but can't envision what the rails controller would look like for `people/update_email_setting.json`

I want to know how to achieve the same using jQuery and Json in a Rails application.  Should my controller handle the json response and then update the DB?

I've love any links on some simple tutorial that shows how to accomplish this from both JS side as well as Rails side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much all you'll need is jQuery's $.post: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Example:

```
$.post('script.rb',{'my_name':'Jason', 'age':22},function(msg){
    console.log(msg); //Where msg is a response from script.rb
});
```

I don't think using Ruby has anything to do with it, other than the fact that you'll post to a .rb instead of a .php.